# Cannot install xserver-xorg after upgrading ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: xorg, xserver

I'm a newbie so if the info I write down in insufficient plz tell me what more to add. I'm trying to use xserver to create a virtual display and launch X to do machine learning using Unity. This is the error message I got:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-5:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all but it is not going to be installed or
                     xorg-driver-input
            Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-all but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: yup already tried that. I also tried to remove everything and reinstall by
`sudo apt-get purge xorg "xserver-*"`
`sudo apt-get purge lightdm plymouth`
`sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`
and this didn't work either.

Comment: You if want Unity - try to install ubuntu-desktop: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. It will pull dependencies.